# python keylogger which save to file every one minute

Tags: python, keylogger

I want to build a keylogger but I want it to update the log file each one minute,
I saw the function `logging.basicConfig(filename = (log_dir + "keyLog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')`
but this function updates the file instantly...
if I leave the filename value empty the function writes to the outstream is there any way to save the output to a string rather than a file???

Comment: _is there any way to save the output to file rather than a file???_ Pardon? Please clarify your question.

Comment: lol sorry.... a string rather that a file